# React Table - table doesn't rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have a const, which should be shown as a table in browser, using method MAP. The problem is below (Cars shown not in a table). Could someone help?

```
const topCars = [
  {manufacturer:'Fiat', model:'m5'},
  {manufacturer:'Nissan', model:'e6'},
  {manufacturer:'Lexus', model:'r'}
]
```

My code:

```
export type NewComponentType = {
    cars: CarsType[]
}

export type CarsType = {
    manufacturer: string
    model: string
}

export const NewComponents = (props: NewComponentType) => {
    return (
        <>
            {props.cars.map((objectFromCarsTypeArray, index) => {
                return (
                    <table>
                        <thead key={index}>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{objectFromCarsTypeArray.manufacturer}</td>
                            <td>{objectFromCarsTypeArray.model}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                )
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

And how it shown in browser:

```
Fiat    m5
Nissan  e6
Lexus   r
```

tried: Rename table tags - nothing happenned

Comment: How are you passing in the data to the `NewComponents` component (you may want to rename that to something more meaningful at some point...)? Have you looked to see if there are any errors in the dev console?

Comment: passinh in App() like this:   return (
        <NewComponents cars={topCars}/>
    );
}
errors in console: 
rning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

act-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <table>. Add a <tbody>, <thead> or <tfoot> to your code to match the DOM tree generated by the browser.

Comment: *"And how it shown in browser"* - Isn't that the expected output?  Or do you mean that it's **not** showing like this in the browser and **should**?  Can you update this to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: OK, your error is telling you that those `<tr>` elements need to be wrapped in a `<tbody>` element. @leronaden. Note that at the moment you're producing one table per object. You probably mean to set up the table outside of the `map` and just use `map` within the `tbody` to generate the rows.

Comment: done, thank you, still have the error with the key, what do I mean about browser: I need name of cars and their models have in the table, right now it showns jus like a siple text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error is showing you that you need a `<tbody>` element to wrap the rows.
2. At the moment you're producing one table per object. You need to move `<table>`, `<thead>`, and `<tbody>` outside of the `map`.
3. Instead of using the index of `map` to produce a key add an `id` property to the objects in your dataset and use that instead.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Cars(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Manufacturer</th>
          <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.cars.map(obj => {
          return (
            <tr key={obj.id}>
              <td>{obj.manufacturer}</td>
              <td>{obj.model}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

const topCars = [
  { id: 1, manufacturer: 'Fiat', model: 'm5' },
  { id: 2, manufacturer: 'Nissan', model: 'e6' },
  { id: 3, manufacturer: 'Lexus', model: 'r' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Cars cars={topCars} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 50vw; }
th { text-align: left; }
td { padding: 0.25rem; border: 1px solid #efefef; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```